# Hibernate specify @Column annotation only once on basic type

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a lot of `Boolean` fields in my class and I'm storing them in `TINYINT(1)`

It's not a problem putting the annotation once, but I have a lot of them and this code looks a bit messy:

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
private Boolean isRescheduled;
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
private Boolean isCancelled;
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
private Boolean isFullDay;
```

Is it possible to specify `@Column` for `Boolean` once?

Comment: You could write your own annotation like `@BooleanColumn` which just inherits from @Column but defines the default values you desire.

Comment: @Korashen I thought making a Boolean wrapper and annotating it with `@Embeddable`. What about this?

Comment: You would still have to put an annotation to each field. So either is a possible approach to reduce the characters in your code. Try out both and see which solution you like best and then go with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need your own `Dialect`.

1. Extend a dialect for your database, for example `MyDialect extends MySQL5Dialect`.
2. In the constructor of `MyDialect` override a type

   `registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "tinyint(1)");`
3. Use `MyDialect` in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` or `hibernate.properties`.